# UITableView insertRows without locking main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to implement infinite scroll like the Facebook app has.

It appears that Facebook is somehow inserting rows or reloading the table view without stopping the current scroll.

Does anyone know how they're achieving this?

When I call insert rows or reload data during a scroll the scroll is stopped dead. Any help would be appreciated.

Not much code to provide just typical UITableView functions.

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:self.paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

or

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

`self.paths` being the paths recently added via the next page request.

I've also added the following method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Which is working correctly now with reloadData being called.  Unfortunately even while this speeds up the addition of cells it still locks the current scroll.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the processing done *before* `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:…` that's blocking the main thread?  Presumably you're parsing data, creating objects, etc. which can stop smooth scrolling.  Perhaps you can show your entire method.

Comment: As far as my version of Facebook goes when I reach the bottom of the UITableView there's a progress indicator that indicates it's loading new content and I can't scroll any farther down until the content is fetched.  What do you mean by it doesn't stop the current scroll?

Comment: @ramzyo - I mean that if you hit the bottom and scroll back up it will continue to scroll without a jump of any sort.

Comment: @AaronBrager - Getting new information for the cells is done on a background thread during which scrolling is fine.  When the completion block is hit for download I set append to my datasource array and reload the tableview.  That reload seems to be as far as my testing has seen right now the only thing locking the scroll.

Comment: Ah ok gotcha.  I think @AaronBrager is on the right track then, because in my experience stutters in scrolling UITableViews have come when my cells include heavy duty content (e.g. images or video) and I'm not being careful with memory management.  Also, I've noticed that in some cases reloadData will cause a tiny little stutter in the UI, so I usually stick with insertRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation: as you mentioned above.

Comment: @ramzyo insertRows was my thought as well however it seems as though estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath doesn't work correctly with insert rows.  Reload data seems to be necessary for that to work.  And by work I mean that estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath should be called instead of heightForRowAtIndexPath until the cell is being presented.  Which also would negate the processing of the data on the cells as being the issue because none of those cells are presented during the scroll and the height isn't being calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so, as far as the stopping of the currently active scroll is concerned the problem came down to a single line of code.  And the solution was just as small.

My TableView has a refresh control on it.  In the method in which I receive the next set of data for the TableView I would call the following.

```
         [refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

My assumption was if it wasn't refreshing that endRefreshing would simply do nothing.

Well...  Apparently that's not the case.  When you call endRefreshing on a refresh control that isn't refreshing it'll stop the tableview scroll.  My fix is as follows.

```
     if(refreshControl.isRefreshing){
         [refreshControl endRefreshing];
     }
```

Now the scroll continues after the next load albeit with some delay.  That delay of course is easier to debug.

That's just the about of overhead involved in calculating the height of the cells being added which is called on all cells when reload is called unless you have

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

So now that I have everything sorted out it's time to create an efficient way to calculate a reasonably close estimate height.

Comment: My suggestion would be to calculate, and cache, the height while you're parsing your data.  That way by the time the cell is about to appear on screen, all you have to do is return a pre-calculated value.

Comment: I went with your suggestion.  I have a background thread running the calculation of the new cell heights.  When this is done I then reload my table on the main thread.  What amazes me now is that if I'm scrolling through existing cells that when reload is called I will still see that slight pause.  Granted it is much less now it's still not competing with the speed in which the Facebook app is reloading.  There must still be something missing but I doubt it's cell for row and now height is returning a float from an array.  Thoughts on what else may be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should start the loading process earlier?  Instead of waiting until they're on the last cell, start when they are 10 cells from the bottom.

Comment: Yea I'm doing it at two thirds currently.

Comment: You could try using the time profiler to figure out what's happening during the spike.